Rxjs sequential API calls results with only one call
I do have such a code:
enum State {
    SUCCESS = 'success',
    ERROR = 'error'
}

const files: File[] = [...some files here];
const toBase64 = (file: File): Observable<string>; //this works 100% fine
const request = (base64: string) => service.upload(base64);

function buildRequest(file: File) {
    return toBase64(file).pipe(
        switchMap(base64 => this.request(base64)),
        map(() => State.SUCCESS),
        catchError((err) => {
            console.error(err);
            return of(State.ERROR);
        })
    );
}

from(files).pipe(
    concatMap(entry => buildRequest(entry)),
    scan((fileNo, result, index) => {
        // some code here
        return fileNo + 1;
    })
).subscribe();

Now, when every api calls return 400, all those calls are executed
When first api call returns 200, only this call is executed, but the rest are not.

please share the code for requestWithMapAndCatchErrorThatReturnsValueForEachState

@NarenMurali I have edited question with more code

Seems some other function caused bad behavior (fileToBase64Observable) which I need to rework. Thank you all :)
